# Is there a way to customize syntax highlighting for javascript files in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-pdt

I would like to customize syntax highlighting for javascript files in Eclipse PDT.

I am working with the Eclipse PDT version 2021-03 (4.19.0) on Windows 7 64 bits. I have installed just the standard Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers with no additional components added.

The Window > Preferences dialog provides me an ability to customize all other file types such as PHP, CSS, HTML or XML but not Javascript, see the image below:

[image]

Am I missed something and there still is a way to have custom JS highlighting in Eclipse PDT?

Or may be what additional components I need to install to make the custom JS highlighting possible for Eclipse PDT?

Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. There is one additional wrong behavior with JS files, namely the Outline sidebar panel is empty for them complaining "There is no active editor that provides an outline".

Comment: Does changing the theme in the preferences _TextMate > Grammar_ for `source.js` change something (e.g. _Eclipse Light_ instead of _Solarized Light_)?

Comment: No, it does not. BTW I just have 2 entries there: _Use 'Solarized Light' theme_ and _Use 'Dark' theme with Eclipse Dark theme_. Seems like the developers of Eclipse just "forgot" about customizing syntax highliting for javascript...

Comment: When you update [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) (in _Help > Install New Software..._ work with the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/latest/)) do you get more themes?

Comment: No, still 2 entries. Actually, I don't want more themes, instead I love to tune syntax coloring in my way, one by one. It's almost a deal breaker for me if I cannot able to have my colors. Very sad.

Comment: Ok, calm down. Those css theme files seem to control many languages not just lavascript. I see less, css, java, even php among identifiers. So may be you somehow tune javascript as well. But what about populating the Outline in the sidebar - it is empty and complains "There is no active editor that provides an outline"?

Comment: Those CSS files can be used for languages/formats supported via language servers (LSP). PDT no longer supports JavaScript via JSDT but now via LSP, by embedding and using the VS code TypeScript/JavaScript language server. This is for better code completion, etc., but also introduces glitches that have not yet been ironed out. You can be the one who cries about these glitches (_"It's almost a deal breaker for me"_, _"Very sad."_, _"Ok, calm down."_), lives with it (just change the colors via CSS instead of via UI) or the hero who fixes it. Your choice.